# Indexing object arrays in MATLAB mex-function

Tags: c++, matlab, indexing, mex

I am trying to access elements of an MATLAB object-array through a mex-function, but I do not know how to access single elements of my MATLAB object-array by indexing in the mex function.

Example:

```
 mxArray *outputValue;       % some outputvalue from method "getSomeValue"
 mxArray *ObjectArray = ...; % Array of MATLAB-objects

 mwSize index = 2;

 % indexing does not work this way!!!
 mexCallMATLAB(1, &outputValue, 1, &ObjectArray[index], "getSomeValue");
```

Do you have any suggestions how to get this indexing working? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what `ObjectArray` contains

Comment: The ObjectArray contains many objects, which have methods and properties. The MATLAb syntax would look like `outputValue = ObjectArray[7].getSomeValue`.

Comment: `mexCallMATLAB` needs a `mxArray*` as the 4th input. Most likely `ObjectArray[index]` are `mxArray`s (note the lack of `&`). however, we can not know.